# Stopping a daemon from running in Android's init.rc

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is there a way to send some kind of event to Android init process to stop re-launching a daemon after it dies ?

Before Android 4.3, the file `init.rc` could be replaced, but now, it's impossible to write over it without flushing the entire filesystem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can communicate with init.rc using `ctl.` system properties.  For example:

```
setprop ctl.stop media
```

will stop the mediaserver, and it will not restart.  Use `ctl.start` to start it, or `ctl.restart` to restart it.

(These are parsed by from `handle_control_message()` in [init.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/jb-mr2-release/init/init.c).)